# form_validation config file in codeigniter (and callbacks)

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

After abusing Google for over an hour, I've found no answers to this question :

When using form_validation.php to your validation rules, Is it possible to pass a **dynamic** value to the callbacks?

```
        array(
                    'field' => 'passwordrepeat',
                    'label' => 'סיסמא חוזרת',
                    'rules' => 'passwordsMatch['myDynamicValue']'
            ),
```

This clearly doesn't work as it passes "myDynamicValue" as a string.
Now, because this config file is loaded so early, this only available resource in it is CI_Loader, which doesn't help much, So I can't access the input class.

**So my question:**
Can a dynamic value pass to the config file, Or should that rule be written **inline** in the controller itself?

Comment: Should probably be written inline in the controller

However are you checking to see if two passwords match? This is built into CI

Comment: It sure is possible, but its so bad approach, like "taking boat for a trip to the Mars". `'rules' => 'passwordsMatch['.$myDynamicValue.']'`

Comment: Thank you both for your comments.
@Chitowns24 - I feel incredibly stupid if it does exist built in codeigniter, could you please point my to some docs? I can't seem to find any on that subject :(

Kyslik - That works only when it's inline in the controller. In the config file $myDynamicValue is not in scope, You cannot call it like that.

Comment: I posted some stuff in the answer, hopefully it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is a bit embarrassing.

The solution to this is that you can pass other field names to your callbacks.
However, remember that what you're passing is the **field** and not the actual value.

To get the actual value you'll need to access it through $_POST['field'].

For example the built in Matches function

```
    public function matches($str, $field)
    {
        if ( ! isset($_POST[$field]))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        $field = $_POST[$field];

        return ($str !== $field) ? FALSE : TRUE;
    }
```

I feel a bit silly :)

Answer (score 2):

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password1', 'Password', 'trim|required|matches[password2]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password2', 'Verify Password', 'trim|required');
```

This is what I have for setting form validation on two passwords. This is what is what comes after you set all of your rules

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        //Validation failed
    }
else
   {
       //Validation suceeded carry on
   }
```

Here is a link to some documentation

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules

Comment: I'll +1 you, But I'll post the actual answer that I just found.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question is little tricky but it's easy to understand. 
The solution for the asked question is here.

Create a `form_validation.php` file under the `application/config/`folder.
and past the code as bellow.

```
$config = array(
               array(
                'field' => 'passwordrepeat',
                'label' => 'סיסמא חוזרת',
                'rules' => 'passwordsMatch['myDynamicValue']'
               ),
            );
```

the rules will loaded automatically available to the  `$this->form_validation->run();` this method.

Also you can append more array, I mean more rules for the different controller.

Hope this will help you.